# Youtube Data Streaming

Tags: youtube-api

How to known if a stream is live (and get amount of current viewers) from a youtube channel id ?

We can have some informations about livestream with [video id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails) but not with channel id.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to use the [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) to use your channelID in checking if the channel has a live stream video. Then if it has, then get the videoId of the video livestream. Now, use the [video.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to get the current viewers. Note you should use the `liveStreamingDetails` as your part parameter here.

You may also  use `https://www.youtube.com/live_stats?v=[videoID]` after you have got the video id from search.list to get the number of viewers